# Retrive user uid details in onBindViewHolder RecyclerView Firebase Adapter | FirebaseUI | Android ,Java

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, firebaseui

here i face a problem with 'holder' as i fast scroll,holder position gets updated (because of recycling behaviour) and after a while onSuccess gets called(as it takes some time for fetching data) 
until then the holder position already changed and holder.mUserFullName.setText(user.getName()) applied to wrong holder position .
This only happens when i fast scroll, if i disable recycling then it solved the problem but i want recycling feature.

```
@Override
        protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull PostVH holder, int position, @NonNull Post post) {

            MyFirestoreDbRefs.getAllUsersCollection().document(post.getByUid())
                    .get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
                    User user=documentSnapshot.toObject(User.class);

                    /*here i face a problem with 'holder' as i fast scroll,holder position gets updated
                    * (because of recycling behaviour) and after a while onSuccess gets called(as it takes some time for fetching data) 
                    * until then the holder position already changed and holder.mUserFullName.setText(user.getName()) applied to wrong 
                    * holder position */

                    holder.mUserFullName.setText(user.getName());
                }
            });

        }
```

[Post Collection Structure in DB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N5cCn.jpg)
[Users Collection Structure in DB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jPHnL.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The below solution, might work it worked for some cases:**

**Call this on your `adapter`:**

```
adapter.setHasStableIds(true);
```

**In your `adapter` override 2 methods, under `onBindViewHolder()`:**

```
@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
return position;
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
return position;
}
```

Comment: its working!!! but the items are not recycling, is it fine with respect to memory optimization??

Comment: Did you remove the recycling.

Comment: Your problem is common, and people usually solved it the way I told you. I don't think there is much you can do about it.

Comment: You have to read more about the recyclerview adapter functionality, other than that if that solved your problem accept the answer so others with same problem know where to look.